# Solr 3,6 Replication Logs out of sync

Tags: solr, replication

I have replication on Solr 3.6 and I want to look at the logs because I have some issue with the timing. But looking there make me even more confused.

Solr Master Log:

```
Oct 8, 2015 6:46:36 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={command=filelist&wt=javabin&indexversion=1346489020771} status=0 QTime=5 
Oct 8, 2015 6:46:36 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/replication params={command=filecontent&checksum=true&indexversion=1346489020771&wt=filestream&file=_6tyd.tii} status=0 QTime=0
```

Solr Slave 1:

```
INFO: Master's version: 1346489020771, generation: 288536
Oct 8, 2015 6:46:10 AM org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller fetchLatestIndex
INFO: Slave's version: 1346489020763, generation: 288534
...

...

Oct 8, 2015 6:46:11 AM org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller downloadIndexFiles
INFO: Skipping download for /solr/solr-home/cores_data/monitoring/index.20140415073723/_6tya.tvd
Oct 8, 2015 6:46:11 AM org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller fetchLatestIndex
INFO: Total time taken for download : 0 secs
```

As you can see the replication on the slave finish before the one on the master has even started. 
Is this a problem with the index version numbers or a problem with the watch on the servers?

Comment: Checking the actual time on the servers should be really straight forward - the file names you're mentioning in both logs aren't the same, so it's hard to say that they're even related.

Comment: @MatsLindh shouldn't the version of the index on the server indicate that those whould be the same?